# v-for not looping on a DIV tag, but works on a TR tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

PROBLEM: `v-for` not looping on a `<div>` tag, but works on a `<tr>` tag

ERROR MESSAGES: None - if using a `<tr>` tag but if using a `<div>` tag...

```
Property or method "week" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based 
components, by initializing the property. 
See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

I'm learning Vue and I'm trying to render a page of calendar cards using data I'm getting from an API. What I'm looking to display is 4 rows, with each row showing 3 cards, and each card contains a table which is the calendar for a particular month. Something like this...

```
+----------------------+   +----------------------+   +----------------------+   
|      Month 1         |   |       Month 2        |   |      Month 3         |
+----------------------+   +----------------------+   +----------------------+
| S  M  T  W  Th  F  S |   | S  M  T  W  Th  F  S |   | S  M  T  W  Th  F  S |
+----------------------+   +----------------------+   +----------------------+
|  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 |   |  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 |   |  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 |
|  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 |   |  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 |   |  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 |
| 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 |   | 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 |   | 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 |
| 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 |   | 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 |   | 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 |
| 30 31                |   | 30 31                |   | 30 31                |
+----------------------+   +----------------------+   +----------------------+
```

All the data that I need for displaying the tables are available in a single JSON array - I'm just having issues looping through parts of it.

I can get the monthly cards and the letters for the day of the week to show. But for some reason, the body of the table that represents the numbers doesn't like it if I use a `<div>` tag to loop through them (Ideally I want to chunk the object of dates into 7 to represent weeks, but that's another issue).

I have a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/79yumwke/11/

(I have an example of something working using the `<tr>` tags here: https://jsfiddle.net/79yumwke/10/)

Basically what I have done is:

1. Used `<div v-for="quarter in _.chunk(calendar,3)" class="row mb-5">` to chunk the `calendar` array into quarters, and create a row that will hold 3 cards.
2. Used `<div v-for="month in quarter" class="col-4">` to get the data for the individual months
3. Used `<th v-for="day in month.days">` to loop through the `days` array to create the header cells for the table.

This all works. What isn't working is the next step:

4. Using `<div v-for="week in month.dates">` to loop through an object (`dates`) within `months` which was created in step #2

```html
            <tbody>                                   
              <div v-for="week in month.dates">                 <!-- v-for Doesnt work here --> 
              <tr>                                              <!-- v-for WORKS here       -->
                <td :class="week.class" :id="week.selector_id">
                  {{ week.day}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              </div>
            </tbody>
```

Below is a snippet of the data (a full example is in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79yumwke/11/)). Essentially the structure is an array of 12 objects which represent *months*.  Each *month* object then contains an array containing the days of the week, and an object containing the individual dates of the month, plus some additional objects that are needed to pad the cells of a table.

```json
calendar: [
    { 
      "days":[ 
         "S",
         "M",
         "T",
         "W",
         "Th",
         "F",
         "S"
      ],
      "dates":{ 
        "2019-12-01":{ 
            "selector_id":"2019-12-01",
            "day":"1",
            "class":"select_date CG_A"
         },
         "2019-12-02":{ 
            "selector_id":"2019-12-02",
            "day":"2",
            "class":"select_date CG_A"
         },
         {... more dates ...},
       },
      "display_month":"December 2019"
   },
   { 
      "days":[ 
         "S",
         "M",
         "T",
         "W",
         "Th",
         "F",
         "S"
      ],
      "dates":{ 
        "dates":{ 
         "0":{ 
            "day":" "
         },
         "1":{ 
            "day":" "
         },
         "2":{ 
            "day":" "
         },
         "3":{ 
            "day":" "
         },
         "4":{ 
            "day":" "
         },
         "5":{ 
            "day":" "
         },
         "2020-02-01":{ 
            "selector_id":"2020-02-01",
            "day":"1"
         },
         "2020-02-02":{ 
            "selector_id":"2020-02-02",
            "day":"2"
         },
       },
      {... more dates ...},
      "display_month":"January 2020"
   },
]
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't put a `<div>` tag directly inside a `<tbody>`. The various table elements have strict rules on which elements are allowed inside which other elements.

Comment: Hmm.. that would explain things. Thanks! Any ideas on how to chunk up an object of objects

Comment: Adding to the comment from @skirtle . Only `<tr>` tags are allowed inside a `<tbody>`.  `Permitted content: Zero or more <tr> elements`. [link to doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)

Comment: I don't really understand what the `<div>` is for. I'd have thought you'd have a `v-for` on the `<tr>` for the rows and a `v-for` on the `<td>` for the 7 cells in each row.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. I wanted to chunk it on the <tr> tags, but I guess _.chunk only works on arrays, and not objects. So my plan was to loop through all of the data using the `<div>` tags and then create a counter and use a v-if on the `<tr>` tags when I'd reached a count of 7.

Comment: @skirtle - you've actually answered my question. I'd like to give you credit. You made me go back and rethink my approach - I'm now creating an array from my objects and then chunking `<tr v-for="week in _.chunk(_.toArray(month.dates), 7)">`. Which is working.